# Facebook LogginButton integration on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Facebook login button into my android application.  I am following the code specified in facebook sdk docs.  The application shows the facebook login button and when I click on it, it brings on the facebook login activity.
The problem is that after I have logged in, NO events are fired.  I would expect onSuccess method to execute if my credentials were accepted by facebook, or onCancel if I cancel the login.

What am I missing?  Also can someone recommend a good facebook-android integration tutorial in addition to what is already on the facebook developer site?

Thank you.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            String test = "";
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            String test = "";
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            String test = "";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your **Activity** for registering **callback**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you write **onActivityResult()**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```